# batch code saving a batch game in a txt

Tags: batch-file

I am using a code to save and load the progress of the game to a text file. When the in formation is saved the information in the text shows up correctly, but when I run the game if the text coding is a sentence it only shows the first word for that sentence.
Example:
This is the code.

```
(echo moves=%moves%)>> save1.txt
(echo ttsu=%ttsu%)>> save1.txt
```

This is what the text file shows.

```
moves=0
ttsu=The troll sees you.
```

This is the load command.

```
if exist save1.txt (
for /f %%a in (save1.txt) do set %%a
goto play
```

This is what the command prompt shows.

```
0
The
```

My question is that is there someway to make the game read the full sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if exist save1.txt (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a  in (save1.txt) do set "%%a"
  goto play
)
```

`=` is a standard delimiter (**edit** the delimiter here is space.`=` is not a delimiter for  `For /f` ) in batch and is automatically included in `FOR /F` options as delimiter.With `delims=` you exclude it.`tokens=*` will ensure you that all tokens are get (i.e. the whole line).And with `%%a` you get only the first token (the `FOR /F` could have many tokens unlike the other usages of `FOR` command  and the nexts - if there is such - can be accessed with `%%b` , `%%c` and so on)

**EDIT**  test added:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:::test code
(
    (echo(moves=0)
    (echo(ttssu=The troll sees you)
)>save1.txt
:::end of test
@if exist save1.txt @(
  for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a  in ("save1.txt") do  set "%%a"
  goto play
)
:play
:::testcode
set ttssu
set moves
:::endof test code
endlocal
```

Comment: and there's no error messages? what is the %errorlevel% ?

Comment: @user3325754 - and be sure you are using my last edit.First I've posted my answer with typo.

Comment: @user3325754 call the file from the command prompt to see if there are any errors

Comment: @user3325754 does the file `save1` exists? what is the output of `SET` command? May be if you share more code will be easier to see whats going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61908/discussion-between-npocmaka-and-user3325754).

Comment: Yes, the file save1 exists. the save1 text document shows the code correctly, but when I open command prompt and run the save1 file the one word and numbers show up fine. The problem is that when the line of code is more then one word or number it only shows up the first number.

Comment: @user3325754 - check my edit.I've added some test code to see if everything is ok.It works for me.Not sure where your issue comes from. Better share your whole code

Comment: Correction - The default FOR /F delimiters are space and tab. The equal symbol is not a default FOR /F delimiter. It is however a token delimiter for the batch parser, but that is not relevant to FOR /F.

Comment: This wont work due to the fact that those variables change in the game. For example moves will change from 1 to 0 throughout the game.

Comment: @user3325754 but you want moves value , right? The name of the variable is not changed?

Comment: yes, but wont I have to change the number manually in order to make move equal 1.

Comment: @user3325754 - That's clear.My edit just shows that the file with the structure you've posted will be parsed .

Comment: My code does work ,but ttsu in the code when it runs only shows the first word not the whole sentence.

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a  in ("save1.txt") do  set "%%a"
that worked